# How to show current line of execution in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How can the current line of execution can be shown or navigated to in MATLAB?

Currently, the closest thing I know of is using dbup/dbdown:

```
K>> dbup
In workspace belonging to OneLevelAboveWhatImLookingFor (line 465)
K>> dbdown
In workspace belonging to ThisIsTheOne (line 37)
```

Comment: `dbstack` should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get actual line being executed in Matlab code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430757/get-actual-line-being-executed-in-matlab-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks AnonSubmitter85!

dbstack displays the current stack trace, thus providing an easy way to navigate to the next line of execution:

```
K>> dbstack
> In ThisIsTheOne (line 37)
  In OneLevelAboveWhatImLookingFor (line 465)
  ...
```